# How do I cross build the latest version of V8 for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: v8, cross-build

I've been trying to cross build V8 for the Raspberry Pi like this:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf
cd ~/
mkdir ~/build/
cd ~/build/
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
export PATH=~/build/depot_tools:"$PATH"
fetch v8
cd v8
make arm.release snapshot=off arm_version=6 armfpu=vfp
```

However it won't compile for so many different reasons. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross Compiling V8 for Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64.

First get the cross compiler and necessary libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-4.9-arm-linux-gnueabihf g++-4.9-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf libc6-armhf-cross
```

Then get depot tools, which will retrieve V8.

```
cd ~/
mkdir ~/build/
cd ~/build/
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
```

Next set the path to depot tools and retrieve the latest version of V8.

```
export PATH=~/build/depot_tools:"$PATH"
fetch v8
```

Now lets prepare the cross build script for building.

```
cd v8/tools
nano ./cross_build_gcc.sh
```

Add -4.9 to the end of CXX,CC,LD, and LINK. So it should look like:

```
export CXX=$1g++-4.9
export AR=$1ar
export RANLIB=$1ranlib
export CC=$1gcc-4.9
export LD=$1g++-4.9
export LINK=$1g++-4.9
```

Save and exit.

Now we have to create a link to asm-generic for the headers to be found while compiling.

```
cd ..
ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/include/asm
```

Now we can start compiling.

```
./tools/cross_build_gcc.sh /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- arm.release arm_version=6 armfpu=vfp armfloatabi=hard
```